# Call directive for conditionally added attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to call a directive if attribute is conditionally added on an element , but i am not getting any solution .

**HTML**

```
    <input type="text" max-length="{{max_length}}" myElement/>
```

Following is the directive

```
App.directive('maxlengthCounter', function($compile, $parse) {

return {
    require : 'ngModel',
    scope : {},
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        var maxLength = parseInt(attrs.maxLength);

        if (maxLength) {
            element.bind("keyup", function() {
                var value = element[0].value;
                element.val(value.substr(0, maxLength));            

            });
            }  

    }
    };
    });
```

and conditionally adding an attribute on element

```
App.directive('myElement',function(){
return {
restrict:"A",
    scope : {},
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
  (attrs.max_length>0?angular.element(element).attr("maxlength-  
 counter",""):'');
  $compile(element.html())(scope);
  }
  });
```

Comment: Show some code, What you tried?

Comment: actually i have created a directive and conditionally adding an attribute on element,then directive is not been called..but if I add attribute statically then the directive is called

Comment: Again, post your code.

Comment: now, provide the solution..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine about the directive call on condition but have various mistakes in your code

1. `<input type="text" myElement` should be `my-element`
2. `(attrs.max_length > 0` should be `maxLength`.
3. Why you are doing `element[0].children[0][index]`?? Whatever you just need to use `element[0]`

Heres the working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rahilwazir/pkqLcg5k/3/)

Comment: demo given is not restricting the length of text according to the value provided